# Add data.table functionality to sf object

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

I read a sf object from a PostGIS-DB like this:

```
parking <- st_read(dsn = con, query='SELECT * FROM "osm"."planet_osm_point"')
```

`parking` has the following class:

```
> class(parking)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"¨
```

I would like to add data.table functionalities to the attribute table.

When I do

```
parking <- as.data.table(parking)
```

the sf object is lost and I only have a data.table. I would like to preserve the geometry.

How can I add data.table to a sf feature collection?

Comment: I don't think you can - I am not aware of {sf} implementing {data.table} methods - but I will follow your question with interest. I may be wrong; which would be good news!

Comment: I don't know how to, but I would just like to replace the underlying "data.frame" with a data.table...

Comment: You could just reclass it as `sf` again, but it won't work with sf methods, most likely.

Comment: See also https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/428 and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2273

Answer (score 1):

### Use `sf::st_as_sf()`

Without a reproducible example it's not possible to know if this will work for you, but when I get `sf` objects with `readOGR()`, I run `st_as_sf()` to convert them into a simple features collection, which behaves like a `tibble` and has methods for `dplyr` verbs, but retains geometry in its geometry column.

I think projection is retained, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I know is not ideal, but as a workaround, you can transform  `sf::st_as_sf(as.data.frame(data_table))`, where `data_table` is your data.table object.

In my case I did all the data cleaning and wrangling steps with a data.table and then transform the result to a sf object